# Surface 3 resolution issue

Tags: display, resolution, microsoft-surface

**Brief Symptoms**

Black bar appears on the top and bottom even running on the same display ratio.

**Detail**

**Case1:**

I am running 1920x1080 on my surface 3, when I Teamviewer to another computer also running with 1920x1080, black bar appear on the top and the bottom.

Local resolution:
[image]

Remote resolution:
[image]

Full screen with Teamviewer:
[image]

**Case2:**

I thought there might be just some compatibility issue about Teamviewer so I have also tested with other software, I tried to play a 1280x720 video on surface 3. As the display ratio of 1920x1080 and 1280x720 is also 16:9, it supposes not displaying a black bar on the top and the bottom also. However, the result is black bar also appearing. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native resolution of your Surface 3 is 1920x1280. When you set the resolution to 1920x1080, the extra 200 pixels in the vertical dimension are divided across two 100 pixel stripes.

Comment: That "2" sure is sneaky, ain't it.

Comment: Yup, my fault.. didn't notice it was 1280 instead of 1080....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set the resolution of the Surface 3 to a ratio
that does not fit the hardware. This causes Windows to reduce the desktop size
to conserve the right ratio and does not relate to TeamViewer.

The native resolution is 1920 x 1280 (214 PPI), giving an aspect ratio of 3:2.
The new resolution is 1920 x 1080, giving an aspect ratio of 16:9.

Windows will try to fit the new and incompatible resolution into the
physical screen by maximizing one of the x or y axes and reducing
the other axe proportionally. This will cause two negative effects :

1. If the resolution for the axe that is displayed to the limits of the screen is not
   the same as the physical resolution on that axe, pixels will be smeared, meaning
   that one physical pixel may represent more or less than one display pixels and will
   be interpolated to some color value. The result is fuzzier display.
   In your case, as you have kept the 1920 resolution on the width,
   this does not happen.
2. The non-maximized axe will be shorter than the screen and the extra space
   will be divided among two black bands, according to the ratio you set.
   As the ratio for width is 1920:1920=1:1, it will be set to 1080 pixels.

You should therefore have two permanent black bands on your screen for the
desktop itself, not having anything to do with TeamViewer.
In effect, TeamViewer at full screen can only scale the display up to the
size of the available desktop space.